# Active Admin Custom Method Parameter

Tags: ruby, action, activeadmin

In ActiveAdmin I'm trying to get a value from a form when I press an action_item on the dashboard, but I'm not sure exactly how to do that this is what I have so far, and it runs, but I would like to be able to pass a parameter for different method calls.

```
    ActiveAdmin.register_page "Dashboard" do

  menu :priority => 1, :label => proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") }

  page_action :scrape, :method => :post do
    #The scraper works, but I don't know how to pass the info
    #from the form from below into this method
   # scrape = Scraper.new
   # scrape.scrape
    redirect_to admin_dashboard_path, :notice => "Ran the scraper!"
  end

  action_item do
    link_to "Run Scraper", admin_dashboard_scrape_path, :method => :post

  end
    content :title => proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") } do
      panel  "Run Course Scraper" do
        para "Run the course webscraper to pull current class list and insert into the Course table in the database"
        form do |f|
          f.input "Session"
        end

      end
    end
end
```

I want to get the input form the form where it says session to pass to the page_action :scrape somehow, any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You could to try to add controller actions to the dashboard page and add f.buttons to the form etc.

Using javascript should also work I guess.